# Performance: Should I consolidate multiple lookup queries into one?

Tags: sql-server

I have two lookup queries that could be consolidated into one.  I see this a lot in the stored procs I deal with (business apps), and I wanted to get some opinions on whether there is any real benefit in consolidating them.

When I run them both, option 1 gives me 1300 reads (2 times), but since the data is already cached, the second set of 1300 reads doesn't cost much, they will always just be logical reads.

Option 2 gives me 1300 logical reads just once.  Is it worth consolidating these, or is it just a question of preference, with no real benefit either way?  I strongly prefer hitting the table just once (option 2).  Am I just being anal?

```
DECLARE @lookupValue1 INT
        , @lookupValue2 INT
        , @key INT = 1000
        , @recType INT = 'X';

-- Option 1:  two separate simple lookups
SELECT  @lookupValue1 = LookupValue 
FROM    DB1.dbo.T1 
WHERE   KeyValue = @key 
        AND RecType = 'Default';

SELECT  @lookupValue2 = LookupValue 
FROM    DB1.dbo.T1
WHERE   KeyValue = @key
        AND RecType = @recType;

-- Option 2: one combined slightly convoluted lookup
SELECT  @lookupValue1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RecType = 'Default' THEN LookupValue END)
        , @lookupValue2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RecType = @recType THEN LookupValue END)
FROM    DB1.dbo.T1
WHERE   KeyValue = @key
        AND RecType IN ('Default', @recType);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a guarantee for (KeyValue, RecType) combo uniqueness?
If they 'should be unique' but not enforced in DB, someone might mess it up later.

- Option 1 would throw an error and prevent unintended behaviour
- Option 2 would hide the problem?

If the constraint is enforced, either way is fine.

btw: I wanted to suggest caching as alternative, but it seems the business logic resides in DB rather than apps.

Comment: +1 Thank you, Gang, good point.  Currently, there is no enforcement in the DB for uniqueness, and I will bring that back to the developers.  It will certainly factor into the solution.  I will wait a bit before accepting your answer, I am curious if there are any other opinions on this performance-wise.

Comment: Performance-wise you didn't give strong justification, given triviality of 1300 reads. However, if either query plan reveals high enough percentage on lookup access or there are frequent locks on lookup then yes option 2 may be considered. imho first step in optimization is finding the bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your input.

Comment: You know about db cache, thus when invoked 100x option1 = 2600 reads, option2 = 1300 reads. As the frequency increases, the benefit diminishes. On the other hand, if db is continuously burdened with memory intensive activities, the cache might get flushed out often. These are just assumptions, to be sure monitor (as my comment above).